# Изменение css стиля элемента при наведении на другой элемент с помощью JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Никак не получается решить проблему, знания JS очень скудные. Нужно заставить квадраты двигаться при наведении на текст над ним.
Как заставить этот скрипт работать для всех элементов с одинаковым классом? Я пробовал через querySelectorAll, но максимум чего удалось добиться - это одновременное движение всех квадратов вниз, без обратного движения. Нужно, чтобы каждый работал по отдельности. **CSS не подойдёт**, в оригинале блоки расположены далеко друг от друга.
Помогите пожалуйста, я уже всю голову себе сломал :(

```js
var dms = document.querySelector('.dm-short-news');
var dmi = document.querySelector('.dm-intro-news');

dms.onmouseover = function(e) {
  dmi.style.transform = 'translateY(50px)';
};

dms.onmouseout = function(e) {
  dmi.style.transform = '';
};
```

```css
.dm-intro-news {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333333;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.wr {display: inline-block}
```

```html
<div class="wr">
<div class="dm-short-news">Текст</div>
<div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
<div class="wr">
<div class="dm-short-news">Текст</div>
<div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
<div class="wr">
<div class="dm-short-news">Текст</div>
<div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Получилось решить проблему собственными силами.

```js
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

var dmns = document.querySelectorAll('.wr');
dmns.forEach(function(dmn) {
  dmn.querySelector('.dm-short-news').addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    dmn.querySelector('.dm-intro-news').style['transform'] = 'translateY(50px)';
  })
  dmn.querySelector('.dm-short-news').addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    dmn.querySelector('.dm-intro-news').style['transform'] = 'translateY(0px)';
  })
});
```

```css
.dm-intro-news {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333333;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.wr {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="wr">
  <div class="dm-short-news">Текст</div>
  <div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
<div class="wr">
  <div class="dm-short-news">Текст</div>
  <div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
<div class="wr">
  <div class="dm-short-news">Текст</div>
  <div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Лучше использовать `mouseenter`, так как ты один раз навел на элемент и все, сработало событие. А `mouseover` при каждом движении внутри данного элемента вызывается одно и тоже событие

Comment: @Air При каждом движении внутри элемента срабатывает `mousemove`, а `mouseover` добавляет срабатывания при переходе на потомка внутри элемента. `mouseenter` игнорирует переходы на потомков и не всплывает от потомка к родителю.  [Подробнее](https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave#%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-mouseenter-%D0%B8-mouseleave)

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, точно !!!!  Перепутал....))))

Comment: @Air Благодарю за корректировку) в данном случае действительно лучше использовать `mouseenter`, но в оригинале у меня внутри элемента `dm-short-news` ещё блок есть, поэтому `mouseover` подходит больше) но тут я виноват, не уточнил этот момент) в ответе пусть Ваше решение останется, спасибо)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста

Answer (score 6):

При этой верстке можно и без JS обойтись

```css
.dm-intro-news {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #333333;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.wr {display: inline-block;transition:2s}
.dm-short-news{display:inline-block}
.dm-short-news:hover~.dm-intro-news{margin-top:20px}
```

```html
<div class="wr">
  <div class="dm-short-news">Текст</div>
  <div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
<div class="wr">
  <div class="dm-short-news">Текст</div>
  <div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
<div class="wr">
  <div class="dm-short-news">Текст</div>
  <div class="dm-intro-news"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это я знаю, но css решение в оригинале не подходит, блоки далеко друг от друга, о чем я указал в посте. Но всё-равно спасибо за участие

Comment: Что значит блоки далеко друг от друга? Если у блоков один родитель, то вполне все будет работать